# Can ComplexInfinity output be trusted?

Tags: evaluation

A quick question regarding evaluation of algebraic expressions at specific values. If for instance I enter

```
(x + 1) (x + 2)/((x + 2) (x + 3)) /. x -> -2
```

mathematica will output $-1$, automatically evaluating the limit at the removable singularity.

In another scenario, I have some complicated algebraic expression $f$ involving $x$'s and $a$'s , and entering

```
f/.x->1/a
```

returns `ComplexInfinity'.

My question is, in general, if I evaluate some expression at a point in this manner, and get `ComplexInfinity' as the output, can I be sure that the expression diverges at this point?

Comment: It would be better to use `Limit`. In your first example, `x+2` terms (probably) cancel before the substitution

Comment: A simple counter-example is `(1 + 2 x + x^2)/(x + 1) /. x -> -1`, where you do need to use `Limit`. Automatic cancellation of factors only works when the factors are explicit, as in your example.

Comment: thanks for the responses. The issue with using Limit on my f is that it doesnt seem to be able to produce an output, since the expression is quite complicated.

Comment: Also I think it's worth noting that in the counterexample ```(1 + 2 x + x^2)/(x + 1) /. x -> -1```, the output is 'indeterminate' rather than 'complexinfinity'. Maybe there is some distinction here

Comment: In the counterexample under consideration the complete output is "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. Indeterminate".

Comment: This is an empty talk without your "some complicated algebraic expression " which makes no sense.

Comment: I understand your concern, but I purposely did not include the specific value of my $f$ since the motivation of my question wasn't to deal with my specific problem but to address a general question, i.e. "in an arbitrary case, if mathematica returns complexinfinity as an output, can I trust that this expression diverges the same way I can trust if the output is some finite value?"

Comment: Maybe I did not make this clear enough, I will edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I can be 100% confident that the expression $f$
>    does not converge at $x=1/a$?

***No:***

```
f = ((E + x)^2 - E^2 - x^2 - 2 E x)/(a x - 1);

f /. x -> 1/a
(*  ComplexInfinity  -- message omitted *)

Limit[f, x -> 1/a]
(*  0  *)
```

In fact, this $f$ is zero:

```
Simplify[f]
(*  0  *)
```

Comment: Disagree with "In fact, this $f $ is zero": up to usual conventions, $f$ is not defined at $x= \frac 1 a$ (assuming, of course, $a\neq 0$).

Comment: @user64494 That's obvious.  Are you saying the function is not zero?  Or are you disagreeing with something else?

Comment: Because $\frac 1 a $ does not belong to the domain of $f$, the substitution x->1/a is incorrect, so its result is unpredictable.

Comment: Let us put $a=2$. Then FunctionDomain[(-x^2 - 2 E x + (x + E)^2 - E^2)/(2 x - 1), x, Reals] performs $x<\frac{1}{2}\lor x>\frac{1}{2} $.

Comment: @user64494 That seems both obvious, as I said before, since I constructed the function that way, and exceedingly trivial. Do you really feel it's necessary to add to any statement about the behavior of a function $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ the proviso "on its domain $A$"?

Comment: thanks Michael, this was essentially the answer I was looking for

Comment: Yes, I do think so. A bug report was submitted by me.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does not evaluate limits unless explicitly asked to do so. What it does is simply evaluate the numerator, then evaluate the denominator, and then evaluate the resulting fraction. The only subtlety is that "evaluate the resulting fraction" means a simple syntactic evaluation, without bothering of possible zeros and thus returning an expression which is not fully equivalent to the input expression. Mathematica also doesn't try to factor the numerator/denominator to check for possible cancellations.

If the resulting fraction turns out to be `1/0`, then it will evaluate to `ComplexInfinity`. If the resulting fraction is `0/0`, then it will evaluate to `Indeterminate`.

Your first example is evaluated as follows:

1. Evaluate the numerator: `(x + 1) (x + 2)` => `(x + 1) (x + 2)`;
2. Evaluate the denominator: `(x + 2) (x + 3)` => `(x + 2) (x + 3)`;
3. Evaluate the fraction (Mathematica performs simple syntax cancellation of terms): `(x + 1) (x + 2) / ((x + 2) (x + 3))` => `(x + 1) / (x + 3)`;
4. Substitute `-2` for `x`: `(x + 1) / (x + 3)` => `-1 / -1` => `1`.

For the example form the comments the evaluation chain is as follows:

1. Evaluate the numerator: `(1 + 2 x + x^2)` => `(1 + 2 x + x^2)`;
2. Evaluate the denominator: `(x + 1)` => `(x + 1)`;
3. Evaluate the fraction: `(1 + 2 x + x^2) / (x + 1)` => `(1 + 2 x + x^2) / (x + 1)`;
4. Substitute `-1` for `x` : `(1 + 2 x + x^2) / (x + 1)` => `0 / 0` => `Indeterminate`.

Comment: `Trace` and `TracePrint` can be quite useful in such situations to see how the evaluation progresses through an expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, $(x + 1) (x + 2)/((x + 2) (x + 3)) $ is not defined at $x=-2$ up to traditional math. Therefore, the substitution $x=-2$ makes no sense.

Comment: @user64494, that's what I meant by "not fully equivalent to the input expression".

Comment: Do you answer the unclearly formulated question under consideration?